# Add a new list item inside a folder using Lists.asmx

Tags: 2007, web-services, development

How can I add a new list item in side an existing folder in the list using the OOB SharePoint Lists.asmx web service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found out the solution:

By using the following batch element you can create an item inside a folder in a list or library

```
<Batch OnError="Continue" RootFolder="http://moss/Lists/CustomersList/FirstFolder">
  <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
    <Field Name="ID">New</Field>
    <Field Name="CustomerName">Robert Hay</Field>
    <Field Name="CustomerAddress">Redmond</Field>
    <Field Name="Title">customer2</Field>
  </Method>
</Batch>
```

The important attribute here is the RootFolder. You need to provide the URL of the folder where you wish to create the item. So right now the RootFolder value is http://moss/Lists/CustomersList/FirstFolder which means thus batch element will create an item inside a prexisting folder **FirstFolder** inside a list **CustomerList**.

Further if there is another subfolder say **SecondFolder** inside the **FirstFolder** folder where you wish to  create the item, then the RootFolder should have this value http://moss/Lists/CustomersList/FirstFolder/SecondFolder

For how to proceed using this batch element this MSDN article proves to be the good source http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems(office.12).aspx

Comment: Looks like the same link I included above.  Sorry I didn't explicitly say it, but my purpose of including the first link was to give you background information on the Lists.asmx web service in case you didn't have any.  My intention was for you to combine that with the information in the second link to derive at your answer.  Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

A great walk-thru on using the Lists.asmx web service is available here: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/SharePointListWebService.aspx

The MSDN library has some info on how to work with lists with folders:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems(office.12).aspx

Comment: Rob, the link above coveres how we can create, update, delete list items. But none of it really shows how we can create a list item inside a folder in the list.

Comment: I added a comment below.